# Access HTML style attribute with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I get a CSS property from the `style` attribute of an HTML element (and ignore the stylesheet/computed properties)?

E.g:

```
<div style="float:left"></div>

function getStyle(element, name) { ... }
getStyle(element, 'float') === 'left';
getStyle(element, 'font-weight') === null;
```

I don't mind either raw JS or jQuery.

Comment: Be careful about what you ask for. HTML attributes and DOM properties are different things, though HTML5 tries to make them reflect each other, they do not in all cases in all browsers. For a long time, Firefox treated attributes and properties as two separate things, IE treated them as essentially the same thing (probably why HTML5 tries to take a middle path, more or less). They are not consistent yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pure JS, This example:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Seems to work, Ill do some more testing before I accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work for you?

```
$('div').attr('style');
```

If you want to parse this further:

```
var getStyles = function(element) {

    // ensure element has style
    if (! element.attr('style')) {
        return {};
    }

    // init styles
    var styles = {}

    // parse style attr
    $.each(element.attr('style').split(/\s*;\s*/), function(i,style) {
        if (style.length) { // a style string ending in ; will cause an empty pair after splitting
            pair = style.split(/\s*:\s*/);
            styles[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
    });

    return styles;
};
```

A couple tests

```
// test an element with style attr
var element = $('<div style="float:left"></div>');
console.log(getStyles(element)); //=> {float: "left"}
console.log(getStyles(element).float); //=> left
console.log(getStyles(element).hello); //=> undefined

// test some element without style attr
var element2 = $('<p>hello</p>');
console.log(getStyles(element2).float); //=> undefined
console.log(getStyles(element2).hello); //=> undefined

​// a bit more complex
var element3 = $('<div style="float:left; background-color:red; color:#555; opacity: 0.5 !important;"></div>');
console.log(getStyles(element3)); //=> {float: "left", opacity: "0.5 !important", background-color: "red", color: "#555"} 
console.log(getStyles(element3).float); //=> left
console.log(getStyles(element3).opacity) //=> 0.5 !important;
console.log(getStyles(element3)["background-color"]); //=> red
```

​

[See it working on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snKrL/5/)

​

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var floating = $('div').css('float');
$('div').css('float','left');
```

To access each styling parameters with jQuery.

Comment: This will return the style-sheet inherited value, and/or the computed value. Which is not what I am after.

Comment: Ok now I see the difference, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you can also access via `prop()` function

```
$('div').prop('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick improvement on macek's code.

This function is in the format asked by Petah. Plus, this function breaks as soon as it finds a match, hence eliminating the need to scan the entire "style" attribute.

```
function getStyle(element, name) {

if (! element.attr('style')) {
    return {};
}
var result= "";

$.each(element.attr('style').split(/\s*;\s*/), function(i,style) {
    if (style.length) { 
        pair = style.split(/\s*:\s*/);
        if(pair[0] == name) {
            result = pair[1];
            return false;
        }
    }
});

return result;
};
```

Js Fiddle for examples on usage : http://jsfiddle.net/rxpMJ/2/